# What is the start/expiry date properties called?

Tags: publishing-page, properties

I need to access the scheduling/publishing start date and expiry date from code-behind (event receiver) - but I'm not sure what they're called. Probably vti_... I'm assuming?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The InternalNames are `PublishingStartDate` and `PublishingExpirationDate`

If you want do it the "right" way then the IDs are in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.FieldId.StartDate` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.FieldId.ExpiryDate`